# Recurrences with modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

Is there any specific way to solve recurrence of form (example):

$$f(x) = (a \cdot f(x-1) + c) \bmod{r} $$
(when recurrence involves modulo).

For recurrence without modular arithmetic I could use generating function method (multiply by $x^n$, sum, manipulate terms and so on) and often solve it in simple way. Could I somehow exploit information about recurrence solution without modulo to solve recurrence with modulo?